# Tab in TabLayout (Android Support Design) doesn't inflate content

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport

I have a `tablayout`, from android design support library:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

With this, I want to populate my tabs. But I'm failing to do that. I can create the tabs, but they fail to inflate their respective content:

[image: Current tablayout, without content.]

Where it should have entries from `LinearListView`, an object similar to a `ListView` imported from this framework:

`compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'`

I tried a great number of examples, but I failed to populate each tab. Any suggestions?

Code:

**JAVA:**
From main fragment:

```
OverviewTabLayoutPagerAdapter adapter = new OverviewTabLayoutPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), productDataContent, getContext());
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

OverviewTabLayoutPagerAdapter:

```
public class OverviewTabLayoutPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "REVIEWS", "VIDEOS", "DEALS" };
    private SearchContent productDataContent;
    private Context context;

    public OverviewTabLayoutPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, SearchContent productDataContent, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.productDataContent = productDataContent;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("TAB_POSITION", String.valueOf(position));

        if (position == 0) {
            return OverviewTab1Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return OverviewTab2Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return OverviewTab3Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
        }

        return OverviewTab1Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
```

OverviewTab*Fragment: (the * means the same code structure applies for every fragment):

```
public class OverviewTab*Fragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    public static final String PRODUCT_DATA_CONTENT = "PRODUCT_DATA_CONTENT";

    private int mPage;
    private SearchContent productDataContent;

    public static OverviewTab*Fragment newInstance(int page, SearchContent productDataContent) {
        OverviewTab*Fragment fragment = new OverviewTab*Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        args.putSerializable(PRODUCT_DATA_CONTENT, productDataContent);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        productDataContent = (SearchContent) getArguments().getSerializable(PRODUCT_DATA_CONTENT);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tab_fragment, container, false);
        LinearListView tabContentListView = (LinearListView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_content_linear_list_view);

        populateOverviewTab*LinearLayout(tabContentListView, productDataContent);

        return view;
    }

    private void populateOverviewTab*LinearLayout(LinearListView tabContentListView, SearchContent productDataContent) {
        ArrayList<> productData = productDataContent.getContent();

        OverviewTab*ArrayAdapter overviewTab*ArrayAdapter = new OverviewVideosArrayAdapter(
                getContext(),
                tabContentListView,
                productData,
                getActivity()
        );

        tabContentListView.setAdapter(overviewTab*ArrayAdapter);
    ...
```

**XML:**
From main fragment:

```
...
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/go_to_store_button"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabGravity="fill" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    ...
```

overview_tab_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
        android:id="@+id/product_content_linear_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="end"
        android:dividerPadding="5dp"
        app:dividerThickness="2dp">
    </com.linearlistview.LinearListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("TAB_POSITION", String.valueOf(position));

    if (position == 0) {
        return OverviewTab1Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return OverviewTab2Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return OverviewTab3Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
    }

    return OverviewTab1Fragment.newInstance(position, productDataContent);
}
```

for this:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("TAB_POSITION", String.valueOf(position));

    if (position == 0) {
        return OverviewTab1Fragment.instantiate(context, productDataContent);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return OverviewTab2Fragment.instantiate(context, productDataContent);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return OverviewTab3Fragment.instantiate(context, productDataContent);
    }

    return OverviewTab1Fragment.instantiate(context, productDataContent);
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is an example with Fragment in Array:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabsViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private CharSequence titlesArray[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when TabsViewPagerAdapter is created
    private Fragment tabsArray[];
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments;

    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public TabsViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence titlesArray[], Fragment[] tabsArray) {
        super(fm);

        this.titlesArray = titlesArray;
        this.tabsArray = tabsArray;
        this.registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();
    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabsArray[position];
    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titlesArray[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titlesArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

In the Java you create the adapter:

```
String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
Fragment[] tabsArray = new Fragment[]{new OverviewTab1Fragment(), new OverviewTab2Fragment(), new OverviewTab3Fragment()};

adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabTitles, tabsArray);
```

And the fragment is something like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class OverviewTab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragmentLayout, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it raises and exception: ``android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment OverviewTab1Fragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public``.

Despite the parameters I inserted are correct, including the class name, which is the 2nd parameter. Any guess or solution?

Comment: Change OverviewTab1Fragment for Fragment.

Comment: I got the same exception. :(

Comment: mmm, I made an Update in the answer is an implementation with another way in the adapter.

Comment: I don't have exceptions anymore, but there isn't any inflated content. I tried to create a layout for each tab and other containers like `ListView`, but still no luck.

Is there any more code I can provide to reach a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am late in the answer, tell me with the last answer (in the update), is working?.

Comment: With your update it is working as it doesn't raise any exceptions, but it still fails to inflate content.